# How to send map parameters using GET for JasperReports Server?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, request, jasperserver

JRXML:

```
 <parameter name="Bla" class="java.util.Map"/>
```

Is report unit execution like that even possible?

```
http://IP/jasperserver/rest_v2/reports/NestedReport/printmap.html?Bla[0]=5
```

I found few simillar questions and tried their suggestions with no extent. While polling jasper logs I can deduce that using notation `Bla=whatever` it creates `java.lang.String` throwing:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Map
    at printMap_1405077234990_851152.evaluate(printMap_1405077234990_851152:169)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JREvaluator.evaluate(JREvaluator.java:231)
```

`Bla[0]=5` is ignored since I assume it tries to find "Bla[0]" parameter.

Why I believe it is possible since it has mechanism for recognising array list parameters, for example if I do `param=bla1&param=bla2` it will create arrayList and pass the values correctly. So if in map case I do `Bla=hello&Bla=hi`I will get cast exception from List to Map.

The parameter class declaration for working lists is also exposed as interface like `java.util.List` so no problem here.

Is there any standard regarding sending the Map values in GET Request for Java? Or parameter recognition is usually solely a benefit exposed by the side API library you use?

Of course if I were to write spring mvc app this task would be no problem at all as I could define default parse regulations for each parameter, but here I am talking to remote *JasperReports Server*.

Comment: You are sending a string in parameter ans trying to get it in Map. Which is not possible.

Comment: I can read exceptions myself and I already explained the error.

Comment: Post your java code. It will be easy to understand your problem.

Comment: There is no Java code. In this test case there is jrxml file with map parameter "Bla", there is rest client plugin for Chrome to execute test requests(which will be fired by spring restClient in prod to remote Jasper Server) and finally there is Jasper Server where jrxml is uploaded and report unit recreated. So the problem is that I can't encode map values inside URL GET request for particular report unit execution and I don't even known if there is a standard for that or if it is possible. If you are willing to dig - it will be on Jasper Server API side , where I am hopelessly lost atm.

Comment: In short words: The enviornment is such as you have Jasper Server and your app which is only able to communicate with Jasper via REST. So when you want to get report result you send request like the one i've shown but it does not allow me to URL Encode map values for request when polling the report - 500 internal server errors which I have shown to you.

Comment: When you send a map from jasper server in key value pair, you can send  key as String and value as string. <parameter name="Bla" class="java.util.String"/>. In this parameter bla will hold key and when you use bla for print then its print value against bla key. For more you need to post your jrxml code.

Comment: I am NOT sending map from jasper server. I see you don't understand what is REST client or what is the flow for jasper report generation. You are not adding any value to the question and you state obvious facts which I am not even asking far. I see zero point in continuing the chat.

Comment: Have you knowledge of jasper? And if you have everything abstract and calling from Rest API then why don't you go to read that API carefully and try to implement it. Nobody can answer you to see 2 line error code.